# How to create a script that when any user logs on starts a script that creates a workspace?

Tags: bash, scripts

I need to create a script which, when any Linux Ubuntu user logs on, starts a script that creates a workspace called WORKSPACE_*NAME OF THE USER in the user's home directory, and when logging out, the script should delete this workspace.
I don't have anything written because I am very new to Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.

Comment: If you are using `bash` as a shell, read about the files [`.bash_login` and `.bash_logout`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Startup-Files-1) in the documentation of Bash. Other shells use files with similar names for the same purpose.